# Install youtokentome in poetry requires Cython, unable to configre correctly

Tags: cython, python-poetry, whisper

I'm trying to convert [whipser-diarization](https://github.com/MahmoudAshraf97/whisper-diarization) to `poetry`

It goes well until I add `nemo_toolkit[asr]==1.20.0`, which depends on `youtokentome` (that name is well thought of, btw)

```
    File "/tmp/tmpexmdke23/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/tmpexmdke23/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
```

So I tried adding `cython` to the dependencies. It works fine if I `poetry shell` and execute `cython`, so it is avaible.

My pyproject so far:

```
...
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
faster-whisper = "0.9.0"
wget = "^3.2"
transformers = ">=4.26.1"
whisperx = {git = "https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX.git", rev = "49e0130e4e0c0d99d60715d76e65a71826a97109"}
deepmultilingualpunctuation = "^1.0.1"
cython = "^3.0.5"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core", "cython"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I added cython to the requires, but that does nothing to prevent the error.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building this package is done in an isolated environment, so it doesn't matter if `Cython` is installed in your current environment.

`youtokentome` has to define its build requirements according to [PEP 518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/).

There seems to be a Pull Request for it for a long time: https://github.com/VKCOM/YouTokenToMe/pull/108

Comment: Mmm. I'll upvote the PR :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to run the following (Python 3.10.12):

```
pip install pybind11                                                          
pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
pip install fasttext
pip install git+https://github.com/gburlet/YouTokenToMe.git@dependencies  
pip install "nemo_toolkit[all]"==1.21
```